# How do I temporily locally set example.com to resolve to 127.0.0.1 without modifying the hosts file

Tags: networking, dns

I've just updated my domain's DNS records but it will take a while for them to propagate across the internet. Until then, is there anyway I can temporarily set my domain, say `box.example.com` to resolve to an IP address, say `127.0.0.1`, locally?

I don't want to modify my hosts files with `sudo echo "127.0.0.1 box.example.com" > /etc/hosts` because in a few hours, the DNS change would have propagated over the Internet anyways.

Can I do this without requiring administrative privileges?

Comment: You meant you want to browse `box.example.com` from the machine itself where the site is hosted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems somewhat vague, so I have prepared two separate answers for you:

1. If what you're asking is whether or not you can write DNS records from the server `/etc/hosts` file, the answer is no. You can change `/etc/hosts` all you like, but it will only affect the server's view of the corresponding IP address, not the Internet's view of the IP address. That is the purpose of DNS -- to resolve a domain name to a specific IP address Internet-wide. Source: [Wiktionary definition of DNS](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)
2. If what you're asking is whether or not you can *alias* an IP address to a domain name, the answer is yes. Editing the /etc/hosts file does just that. In all likelihood, the best way to do that temporarily is simply to `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, add the alias in question, such as `127.0.0.1 box.example.com`, and later remove it. To alias an IP *without administrative priveleges*, as per your request, I honestly do not believe that it is possible. If I come across any information to the contrary I will update my answer immediately.

Comment: The second one answers my question. So there's no way to do that without editing the `/etc/hosts` file. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Sorry I had to bear bad news.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand what the `/etc/hosts` file does.

The `/etc/hosts` file does *not* propagate across the internet.  It only works and affects local lookups on your computer itself.  For example, I have `10.0.50.123        mydmzbox` in my `/etc/hosts` file - that 'hostname' doesn't actually resolve to anything anywhere else, Internet or otherwise, and just exists as a connection alias for my computer only.

If you add your entry to `/etc/hosts` it will only affect your local computer, and nothing else - there's no need to worry about the `/etc/hosts` change propagating out to the internet.  (What you're thinking of is a zone file within Bind, but that is not the same as putting an entry in `/etc/hosts`.)